# A variable in an if-else clause is being pulled into the subsequent clause in Google Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms

I'm building a script that sends an email to specific people based on how a Google Form is filled out.  e.g., if scenario A is selected, Sabrina is emailed, and if scenario B is picked, Salem is emailed.  I have it set up so that the email address, subject line, and email body change depending on the selected option, and would like to do the same for the recipient name as well, but for some bizarre reason, the recipient's name is being applied to the subsequent part of the if-then clause.  e.g., if scenario A's recipient is supposed to be Sabrina, recipient instead shows up as "undefined", and scenario B is addressed to Sabrina instead (and Salem to scenario C instead of Zelda).

Below is my code--is there something incredibly basic I'm missing here??  All of the other variables are properly assigned as expected.

```
var body = "Hi "+ recipient+", <p></p> You have a new research request, submitted by "+FormattedFirstName+" "+FormattedLastName+".  Study details are listed below."";
    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
      if (StudyType === "ScenarioA") {
        var emailsubject = ("New " + StudyType + " Study Request");
        var recipient = "Sabrina";
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: "sabrina@gmail.com",
          subject: emailsubject,
          htmlBody: body
      });
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 23).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      }
      else if (StudyType === ScenarioB") {
        var recipient = "Salem";
        var emailsubject = ("New " + StudyType + " Study Request");
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: "salem@gmail.com",
          subject: emailsubject,
          htmlBody: body
      });
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 23).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      }
       else if (StudyType === "ScenarioC) {
        var recipient = "Zelda";
        var emailsubject = ("New " + StudyType + " Study Request");
        MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: "zelda@gmail.com",
          subject: emailsubject,
          htmlBody: body
      });
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 23).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use `recipient`? I see only assignments.

Comment: recipient is in the very first row, defined in the variable body (and then is called by extension in htmlBody).

Comment: Aha. Then you probably need to run the code that assigns to receipt *before* you use it to create the html body.